# How to get access to Docker's volume from Shiny app?

Tags: r, docker, shiny, shiny-server

I have a dockerized Shiny app that needs to read data from some RDS files. These RDS files must be updated a couple of times a month. I thought resolve it with a volume, but I have a problem with permission's user. The Shiny app runs as shiny user and the app doesn't have read permission over the volume's dir. I can't run a "chown shiny:shiny" command because I lose permissions over the volume's dir in host machine. Is there any way to solve this problem?

Thank you in advance!

Dockerfile

```
FROM rocker/shiny:3.5.3
...
COPY shiny-server.conf /etc/shiny-server/shiny-server.conf 
COPY .Renviron /srv/shiny-server 
RUN chown -R shiny:shiny /srv/shiny-server/ 
RUN cd /srv/shiny-server && git pull origin features/DTedit
```

shiny-server.conf

```
# Instruct Shiny Server to run applications as the user "shiny"
run_as shiny;

# Define a server that listens on port 3838
server {
  listen 3838;

  # Define a location at the base URL
  location / {

    # Host the directory of Shiny Apps stored in this directory
    site_dir /srv/shiny-server;

    # Log all Shiny output to files in this directory
    log_dir /var/log/shiny-server;

    # When a user visits the base URL rather than a particular application,
    # an index of the applications available in this directory will be shown.
    directory_index on;
  }
}
```

This [article](https://github.com/rocker-org/rocker/wiki/Sharing-files-with-host-machine) talk about this but I'm not able to get it resolved.

**UPDATE:**
Finally, according to r2evans's comment the solution is give 755 permissions via chmod to the shared dir (volume). On this way, on the host side I can continue updating RDS files and on the docker side Shiny app can access and read the files because "5" permission to others. To effectively refresh the data, I need to run this Docker command after overwriting RDS files into volume's dir:

```
docker exec -it container_name sh -c "cd /srv/shiny-server/ && touch /srv/shiny-server/restart.txt"
```

Comment: Please provide at least *some* context: ideally, a minimum shiny app and the docker command used to mount the volume. How are the RDS files being updated ... internal to shiny or some extrinsic process?

Comment: RDS files are updated overwriting them in the volume's dir on the host side. I use the -v flag in order to mount the volume. On the docker side, the owner of volume's dir is the host's UID, but since Shiny app runs as shiny user does not have permission over volume.

Comment: That suggests that the mode of the file does not allow reading by "other" (non-user, non-group) users. In general, many files on the system are readable by `shiny:shiny`. This could be the mode on the host or an inherited mode based on however you mount it in your `-v` arguments.

Comment: I just updated the post with one solution based on your comment. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Try this, go inside of your running container execute `id` . this will tell you what is uid of user inside docker container, then chown your mounted files to that id.
let me know if it worked.